# Is a moisture barrier needed over gyp-crete (gypsum concrete) for wood / bamboo flooring?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, moisture, underlayment

In a condo, and just discovered that the floor is actually gyp-crete, presumably over wood. Is a moisture bnarrier necesary? This is above grade.

Comment: Above grade but is the concrete on the ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

- It depends

Above grade doesn't mean above ground, necessarily.

If you are referring to concrete that rises out of the ground - then yes, you should put down a moisture barrier.  Concrete is porous and moisture will (slowly) permeate the concrete if there's enough moisture around.

However, if the concrete is suspended - a concrete floor above ground with air below it - then no you won't need a moisture barrier.

Comment: It's a second floor unit

Answer (score 1):

It further depends on the kind of floor you're installing.  Greebo is right about the barrier, but a "just in case" application if you're not sure might still be redundant.  Vinyl flooring will be far less adversely affected by water than, say, hardwood.
You mightn't need a moisture barrier, but if you're going with hardwood, you'll need to be nailing the floor down.  That will mean you need a subfloor of some sort, since gypcrete doesn't hold nails well at all.